# NServiceBus service crashes with exception in windows Log Viewer

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

I have NServiceBus as a host, and sometimes the service crashes and I see the following in the windows Event Log:

```
 Application: NServiceBus.Host.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Common.Logging.ConfigurationException
Stack:
at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendMessage(System.Collections.Generic.List`1<NServiceBus.Address>, System.String, NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.MessageIntentEnum, System.Object[])
at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendMessage(NServiceBus.Address, System.String, NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.MessageIntentEnum, System.Object[])
at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.NServiceBus.IBus.Send(System.Object[])
at MyApp.AutomaticChanger.SendNotificationToClient(System.String, 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

my SendNotificationToClient method does indeed send a message to the bus. but the reason it crashes is not clear to me.

Comment: Is this deployed or on your development machine?  Is there an inner exception you can log or debug?

Comment: Based on the exception, I'm guessing you are hitting an error condition and trying to log it, and the logging itself is failing.

Comment: @PhilSandler it's on the production server.

Comment: @PhilSandler the message send code is surrounded by try-catch blocks - are you referring to the log4net call I make in the catch block?

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking you log in your catch block, and the call to the log is failing.  Just an educated guess, though.

Comment: That this is a Common.Logging.ConfigurationException indicates a problem with the logging config. Can you post that?